# Why are these 4 threads locking up when using a semaphore?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, semaphore, race-condition

In a system which may have many, many threads, I am trying to ensure that only four instances of a class are instantiated at a time and maybe released after 5-60 seconds. The instances are created at the start of each thread and destroyed when the process in the thread ends.

I also want to prevent only one instance being constructed at a time. So my logic is to use a lock during Object instantiation but also wrap the overall thread logic with a semaphore.

```
private static readonly object padlock = new object();
private static readonly Semaphore mutablelock = new Semaphore(0, 4);

// called at the start of a long running thread
public static Object GetNewInstance()
{
    // semaphore used to prevent more than 4 objects from existing at any time
    mutablelock.WaitOne();

    // lock used to prevent more than one object being instantiated at a time
    lock (padlock)
    {
        var instance = new Object();
        return instance;
    }
}

// called at the end of a long running thread
public static void ReleaseInstance()
{
    mutablelock.Release();
}
```

The program has four threads which (when viewed with debug stop points) each stop at the `mutablelock.WaitOne();` line and never progress any further.

Comment: Without seeing *any* code that calls `ReleaseInstance`, one can only suppose that not all code paths that need to are calling it at the appropriate time.

Comment: why do you want to block your constructor from being created?

Comment: It’s not thread safe.

Comment: "many many" is not descriptive.  Some people might think that fifty threads is "many many."  Somebody else might imagine ten thousand threads.

Comment: Your description of the problem makes it sound as if it is never possible for more than four of the "many many" threads to do any work at the same time.  If that's the case, then why not just use four threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're constructing your `Semaphore` in such a way that all entries have been reserved. The [`Semaphore` constructor taking two arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1hct27h(v=vs.110).aspx) has this to say:

> If *initialCount* is less than *maximumCount*, the effect is the same as if the current thread had called `WaitOne` (*maximumCount* minus *initialCount*) times. If you do not want to reserve any entries for the thread that creates the semaphore, use the same number for *maximumCount* and *initialCount*.

So make this change:

```
private static readonly Semaphore mutablelock = new Semaphore(4, 4);
```

Comment: The first ‘if’ in that paragraph seems superfluous.